# VBA: How to identify cells that have spaces at the beginning or end of the cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset that is 80 columns by 200,000 rows. This data contains cell values that have beginning or trailing spaces. I need to identify which cells have those spaces.

If the  dataset were smaller I could easily write a couple of for loops to check each cell for spaces. However, considering the size of the data, checking each cell would slow excel down (if not crash it). I anticipate that auto filter would end the same way.

Is there any way to efficiently check the dataset for spaces at the beginning or end of a cell value, without going cell by cell via loop

Comment: do you need to remove the spaces or just call them out?

Comment: You could try Home>Editing>Find & Select (Ctrl+F) and in the Find what box put in " * " <space><asterisk> for leading spaces and " * " <asterisk><space> for trailing. 'Find All' then Ctrl+A with focus in the results to select them all. Then have an outer loop for the areas and an inner loop for the cells in each area. Is a possibility?

Comment: @Doug Coats: I just need to call them out

Comment: Do you need to generate a list of the rows?  Or just be able to ID them on the sheet?  If the latter, you could just use conditional formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim sheetArr As Variant
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    sheetArr = sh.UsedRange
    rowC = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    colC = sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    For i = 1 To rowC
        For j = 1 To colC
            If Left(sheetArr(i, j), 1) = " " Then
                sh.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            End If
            If Right(sheetArr(i, j), 1) = " " Then
                sh.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

I tested this on a 1 million row sheet and was done within 5 seconds. This should be good enough.

[image]

Comment: Sorry if it wasnt clear, but i only want to identify the cells. I don't need or want to remove them. Thanks for the input though

Comment: @Adit2789 this is what you want :) Highlights cells with extra spaces

Comment: Sorry. I saw the text before the code. You said something about removing the spaces, so i overlooked the code. My bad. How is this any different than going cell by cell however?

Comment: What version of Excel has a 2 million row sheet?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld 2 million or 200,000 ?

Comment: @RonRosenField sorry I mistyped - it was a 1 million row sheet. i attached a screen shot

Answer (score 2):

1. Select all cells you want to use
2. Click on Home -> Conditional formatting button -> New Rule
3. Scroll down to "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Assuming your current cell is A1, type in the following

   =OR((RIGHT(A1,1)=" "),(LEFT(A1,1)=" "))
5. Press format button, click on "Fill" an choose a color for fill
6. Press "ok", "ok".

The cells should be highlighted now

Comment: That seems to be an easiest method to identify the cells with criteria. Good one.

Answer (score 0):

A loop might be slow if you query the workbook cell by cell.
Instead, a loop querying a variant array will be much much faster:

```
Dim i as long
Dim j as long
Dim a() as Variant
a = yourrange.value
for i = lbound(a,1) to ubound(a,1)
  for j = lbound(a,2) to ubound(a,2)
    if left(a(i,j),1) = " " or right(a(i,j),1) = " " then
     'beginning or ending with " "
    end if
  next j
next i
```

Another option would be to copy/paste the data to notepad++ for example and then use the extended search function with "\t " and " \t" as well as "\r\n " and " \r\n" in order to find " " next to tabs and breaks which separat columns and rows respectively

Comment: .value is unnecessary when assign a range to an array and you dont offer a way to actually identify them, lol

Comment: Within the if, wouldn't a(I, j).Font.Bold work? Or fill the cell with a color?

Comment: @Doug. Of course yourrange would need to be defined. And .value is not superfluous since you could also use .Text or .Value2.

Comment: @Adit: No, this would not work as the variant array can hold only variants (e.g. number or texts) but no ranges. So a(i,j) gives you just a variant

Comment: Good to know. I've never needed to use variants before, so I'm not completely clear on their usage. Either way, how would you identify the cells?

Comment: [code]left(a(i,j),1) = " " or right(a(i,j),1) = " "[/code] cuts the first and the last character from the currently checked cell content (which is in [code]a(i,j)[/code]) and checks whether it is a blank